# Refusing Only Spaces in an input in a form in html

Tags: html, forms, validation

Form field is message. I don't want users to be able to send only spaces as a message. So,

" " and "   " and "         " and "                   " and so on will go to something like

```
if (x==null || x=="" || x==" " || x=="  ") {
    alert("At least 8 characters are required!");
    return false;
}
```

but I need to arrange the 'if' area in a way that it will not accept only 'space' character, no matter how many 'space' characters the user puts (And at least total of , let's say, eight characters need to be put).

Thank you.

Comment: Use regular expressions. In many languages [`\s`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) matches any "white space" characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so you know, there are many ways to do this, but I'll give you a fairly simple one.

Use `.trim()` to remove all whitespace:

```
if(x.trim() === "" || x === null){
  alert("At least 8 characters are required!");
  return false;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Pn4bB/2/)

Alternatively, you could remove the space characters like this:

```
x = x.split(" ").join("");
if(x === "" || x === null){
  alert("At least 8 characters are required!");
  return false;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Pn4bB/1/)

If neither of those work for you, try [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` eliminates all spaces, so try

```
if (x===null || x.trim() === "") {
    alert("At least 8 characters are required!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. x.trim() != "" or x.trim() === "" ?

Comment: @IMayNeed Thanks for the notice. I'm usually not that oblivious :P